# flask: Loading JS libraries in specific templates over loading in base template

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask, datatables

Let's say I have a `Flask` app, and Flask being a micro web framework, I turned to `datatables` to render my tables (with `jquery` of course).

Now my template are the following:

```
base.html (base template for all other templates)
index.html
other templates
users.html (this is the only template that uses datatables)
```

It is customary to link used JSs to the `base.html` template. Now, considering that only one (`users.html`) uses datatables (`datatables.js` and `jquery`), would it benefit my app in terms of load time if I load jquery and datatables only in users.html?

Currently, I am loading the JS libraries in the base template. I have not attempted to benchmark load times yet.

Comment: Why would you want to load the datatables javascript in every page even if it's not being used? Mind you the impact is very likely negligible, CSS+JS for datatables with all plugins minified is a bit under 3MB, but if you care about positioning, SEO, Time to First Byte and all that crap you might not want to load it every page.

Comment: @Daviid, do you mean I should only load datatables in `users.html`?

Comment: You should only load a JS library where you're going to use it.